# How to switch to modal window in the background

Tags: keyboard, quicksilver

I don't know if this problem is specific to Quicksilver or a general problem with modal windows. I use QS to launch an applescript:

```
"run 'command' with administrator privileges"
```

But the modal window from QS to enter my password appears without focus. I can't I need to click on the window with the mouse in order to be able to activate it. I would guess that this is because QS has launched the applescript "in the background" as it were, and already returned focus to the previous app.

Is there a way to switch to this modal window using keyboard actions? It's something I need to do every morning and it's very annoying to have to switch over to it with the mouse every time. I can't command-tab to Quicksilver when the dialog is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was obvious once I saw it: first make Quicksilver the foreground app, then it won't return focus to another app when the script runs.

```
tell application "Quicksilver" to activate
do shell script "pmset -c displaysleep 180" with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 2):

You can focus SecurityAgent:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "ls /var/root" with administrator privileges' &
open -a SecurityAgent
```

Displaying dialogs:

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    --activate
    display dialog "" default answer ""
end tell
```

⌃F6 (Move focus to the floating window) doesn't work with the password dialogs, and Witch doesn't include them either. You might use a script like this though:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with p in {"SecurityAgent", "CoreServicesUIAgent", "loginwindow"}
        if exists process p then
            tell process p
                if windows is not {} then
                    set frontmost to true
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

CoreServicesUIAgent displays Gatekeeper and quarantine dialogs. loginwindow displays many of the dialogs shown when logging out.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I couldn't get the examples above to work in my script, but they pointed me in the right direction.